# Google Tag Manager submit form data

Tags: javascript, seo, google-tag-manager

I'm trying implement GTM like for passed values from search form after post request.

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'check-availability',
            'avCheckIn': 'April 3, 2014', 
            'avCheckOut': 'April 7, 2014',
            'location': 'Form name’,
            'guests': '2',
            'propertyName': 'Property name'});
```

How to create this tag, rule and macros in GTM

Answer (score 0):

GTM works with javascript, so it does not catch POST values. You'd need to catch the values serverside, render them into your page code as key/value paris in a datalayer. Then you can create new macros if the dataLayer type and get the values by specifying the key.

You might change your form to use the get method, in which case you could catch parameters via url macros (macro type "url", component type "query", "query key" is the key for the variable you want to get from the url).

But as long as you're using POST values there is no way to do this with GTM alone, you'd need some sort of server side scripting to output the values into the page code.